# Construct a martingale with a given distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

Given a random variable Y, is it possible to construct a martingale M such that $$M_1 \stackrel{D}{=} Y$$

I'm not sure how to go about proving that such an M exists under such general conditions, but I feel like this is definitely a standard question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If random variable $Y$ takes values in $\mathbb R$, you can find a measurable function $f: \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, such that $f(N)$ has the same distribution as $Y$, where $N$ is a standard Gaussian random variable.

Now, for a Brownian motion $B_t$, define
$$ M_t = E(f(B_1)|\mathcal F^B_t)$$

Comment: How is that first result proved? The one where you can find a measurable $f$ such that $f(N)$ has the same distribution as $Y$?

Comment: Let $g$ be the cdf of $Y$, ang $h$ that of N, and $f= g^{-1}h$